# How to remove "taint" for Findbugs "Find Security Bugs"

Tags: java, security, findbugs, taint, find-sec-bugs

I am using the "Find Security Bugs" plugin for Findbugs: https://find-sec-bugs.github.io/

Many of the detectors use "Taint analysis" to raise their warnings.

Is there any documentation on how to remove "taint" from a value?

I can't find any docs about this on their site, and I have been poking around their source code and can't figure it out:

- [src/main/java/com/h3xstream/findsecbugs/taintanalysis](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/tree/1d288ef15122a4d883343769dd221cbe7bbeecb1/plugin/src/main/java/com/h3xstream/findsecbugs/taintanalysis)
- [src/main/resources/taint-config](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/tree/1d288ef15122a4d883343769dd221cbe7bbeecb1/plugin/src/main/resources/taint-config)
- See also [this wiki page "Injection detection"](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/wiki/Injection-detection)

The tool is identifying a possible injection bug from code like:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

public Response get(String x, String y) throws IOException {

    String url = String.format("%s/%s",
            x,
            y);

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url); // HERE

    ...
}
```

I have fixed this bug to my satisfaction with:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import static com.google.common.net.UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper;

public Response get(String x, String y) throws IOException {

    String url = String.format("%s/%s",
            urlPathSegmentEscaper().escape(x),
            urlPathSegmentEscaper().escape(y));

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    ...
}
```

... but the tool is still flagging a possible bug. I believe that this is because it does not recognise "`com.google.common.net.UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper()`" as removing Taint here.

How can I persuade it otherwise? 
If I cannot, what sanitisation techniques can I use here that the tool does recognise?

Answer (score 0):

An answer was given on the issue tracker : https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/issues/346#issuecomment-334286419